# Form Submit Not Wait For Sweet Alert Confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, sweetalert

I have CRUD and want to add confirmation box with Sweet Alert. But I just add it to Create Form. Clearly simple, I just wanna like this :

- Input Data
- Click Submit Button
- Sweet Alert confirmation appear
- Click 'Yes'
- Data store to database
- Return to Read table

This my code :

```
<!-- Form -->
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="tmbhunit" action="<?= base_url() ?>C_unit/create">
<!-- Card Icon -->
<div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="red">
    <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
</div>
<!-- End Card Icon -->

<!-- Card Content -->
<div class="card-content">
    <!-- Card Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title">Tambah Data</h4>
    <!-- End Card Title -->
    <hr>

    <!-- Label Input -->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left" for="namaunit">Nama Unit</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaunit" name="nm_unit" required placeholder="Masukan nama unit..">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Label Input -->
    <!-- Label Input -->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left" for="almtunit">Alamat Unit</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="almtunit" name="alamat" required placeholder="Masukan alamat unit..">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" value="Tambah" />
                <input type="button" name="cancel" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Label Input -->

</div>
<!-- End Card Content -->
</form>
<!-- End Form -->
```

This is javascript :

```
$("#tmbhunit").submit( function () {

var nm_unit = $("#namaunit").val();
var almtunit = $("#almtunit").val();

swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    closeOnConfirm: true
}, function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    event.preventDefault();
        return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

});
```

Actually, the script is working, the sweet alert has appeared also, but the form Submitted ahead without giving me a chance to confirm that, I've tried every tutor but not once working.

Comment: The alert runs asynchronously, so essentially you say this:  show an alert, finish submit (submits), wait for user input, preventDefault after user clicks alert's "yes" (which has no effect).  You need to put the `event.preventDefault()` outside the `swal()` and then post the form via code (or move the alert out of the submit method).

Answer (score 1):

Use before submit instead of submit function like below

```
 jQuery("body").on("beforeSubmit", "form#tmbhunit", function() {
    // You logic
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Given that it *always* returns false, I don't see how that can possibly be the case. There's also no `beforeSubmit` event by default, so that must be raised by a library you're using.

Comment: yes rory sir you are right.. my code is works when submit the form without refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you need to *always* stop the default behaviour of the `submit` event handler in your jQuery code.

You can then submit the form from the DOM Element directly in the `if` statement when the user confirms their choice, like this:

```js
$("#tmbhunit").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nm_unit = $("#namaunit").val();
  var almtunit = $("#almtunit").val();
  var form = this;

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    closeOnConfirm: true
  }, function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="tmbhunit" action="<?= base_url() ?>C_unit/create">
  <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="red">
    <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
  </div>

  <div class="card-content">
    <h4 class="card-title">Tambah Data</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left" for="namaunit">Nama Unit</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
          <label class="control-label"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaunit" name="nm_unit" required placeholder="Masukan nama unit..">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left" for="almtunit">Alamat Unit</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
          <label class="control-label"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="almtunit" name="alamat" required placeholder="Masukan alamat unit..">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" value="Tambah" />
          <input type="button" name="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back()" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks before, the Form submitted work without passing the sweet alert, BUT when i click 'Yes' Button, it's nothing happen, just stuck

Comment: Check the console for errors. As you can see from the snippet above, this should work fine

Comment: @Z.Norz where you want to post these data means which `controllers` `function`?

Comment: in create() function

Comment: i got this error :

Unknown parameter "closeOnConfirm"
setParameters @ sweetalert2.js:486
modalDependant @ sweetalert2.js:806
sweetAlert @ sweetalert2.js:1403
(anonymous) @ create:387
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3

Comment: That error is because there is no `closeOnConfirm` property: in either [Sweet Alert v1](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#configuration) or [v2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/)

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: Remove that property

Comment: ok the error gone but still same, nothing happen when i click yes button

Comment: I'm having exact same problem. Nothing happens when i click yes button, did you make it work? Thanks!

Comment: i got an error `Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function`

Comment: In which case i'd suggest starting your own question about the issue, as something in your logic does not match the conditions above. I would also appreciate you removing the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('form').submit(function (e) {
   var form = this;
   e.preventDefault();
   setTimeout(function () {
    form.submit();
   }, 5000);
   $(Swal.fire({
      html: "<h5 style='color:#099942;font-weight:600;'>your text here...</h5>",
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: false
      })).appendTo("body");
});
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).